# Can we concatenate two properties in Hibernate HQL query?

Tags: hibernate

Lets say I have one table with two columns `firstname` and `lastname` with String datatype. Normally I write my hql query like

```
"select firstname,lastname from contact"
```

Can I write a hql query which concatenates both property ?

Maybe something like `"select firstname+lastname as fullname from Contact"`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
select concat(c.firstname, c.lastname) as fullname from Contact c
```

or, if you want a separator:

```
select concat(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) as fullname from Contact c
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions).

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to add `","` or `space` in between ?

Answer (score 25):

You may create a calculated column in your entity:

```
@Formula(value = " concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) ")
private String fullName;
```

And in your HQL you just refer to this field as you would do to any other.

In your case, you can do:

```
"select fullName from Contact"
```

Comment: does this result in an actual database column ? or is this more of an in-memory thing ?

Comment: @bvdb i'm not a database expert, but I would say it depends on the DB engine. What you can do is to log the SQL statement and execute an explain plan.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use || concatenation operator:

```
"select c.firstName || ' ' || c.lastName as fullName from Contact"
```

allthough it may be confusing to read.

Answer (score 3):

I did it so with hql

```
public List<Contract> findContracts(String fullName) {
    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contract c where :fullName = concat(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname)");
     q.setString("fullName", fullName);
     return q.list();}
```

Answer (score -1):

public String getname(){return first_name+last_name;}

use this method will you see answer