# combining 2 or more properties in Hibernate Restrictions criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to perform  search action on entered string. whatever  user  enter  it  should search on  first name  and last name  column.

```
   //pseudo hql query
     Select   E.someproperty ....  from  Entity E    where   upper(E.firstName || '' || E.lastName)  like  upper(+userEntered+'%')  //
```

In above code I combined   two column   and did  search on it. I want similar  functionality  using  hibernate criteria.
 I have  tried  following query  but it didn`t  work

```
 empCriteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.ilike("firstName",  
   userEntered, MatchMode.START)).add(Restrictions.ilike("lastName", userEntered, 
MatchMode.START)));
```

I  know  it is  just  or condition..please let me know is  there way  to  combine  two  column  and  do search  on  using  criteria  query

Comment: What "didn't work" about it? Can you be more specific? What you've got there looks right.

Comment: that criteria  query  separately checking  two column and 'ORing' result.I want to combine  both  column and then  perform  search operation on it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with `Restrictions`.

I'd strongly recommend doing it in HQL rather than with an SQL restriction in a `Criteria` instance. You're in danger of breaking the portability if you start using SQL: the point of Hibernate is to abstract that layer away.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910428/can-we-concatenate-two-properties-in-hibernate-hql-query) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Resrtictions.sqlRestriction()` with SQL clause.

Comment: This should be in a comment rather answer box. Either provide a proper answer or it will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to do like that. Since You need to merge two columns. So Please try in sqlRestrinctions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, for example add in your mapping hbm.xml file this( || means concat in oracle):

```
<property name="completeName"
   formula="FST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME"/>
```

simply add in java bean, the new proprieties:

```
private String completeName;
public String getCompleteName() {
    return completeName;
}
public void setCompleteName(String completeName) {
    this.completeName = completeName;
}
```

After finally you can get this concatenation in your restrinction:

```
Criteria.add(Restrictions.like("completeName","%"+userEntered+"%").ignoreCase();
```

ps: if you are mapping directly on java bean us the formula in this way:

```
@Formula(value="FST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME")
private String completeName;
```

Comment: if || don't work use: concat(concat(FST_NAME, ' '), LAST_NAME)