# How can I set a @Transient field value after query? Using Hibernate Criteria for query

Tags: hibernate, criteria, default-constructor

Let me describe the question in full details to avoid the X-Y situation.

I want to use Hibernate to do a `LIKE` query to retrieve registries in table `Product` where the `Product`'s `User` has my input string as full name. Something in SQL like:

`SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_user IN (SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?)`

I am happy with Hibernate Criteria, but in this case it seems to have no way to do combining columns values searching in Criteria (I don't want to generate some customized Criteria aside), so I am trying to use `Restriction.sqlRestriction()`, but I found that in some case `createAlia()` is quite easy while `sqlRestriction` is impossible, such as:

```
criteria.createAlias("user.supervisor.teamleader", "uT");
```

So, I am considering another solution: creating a `@Transient` field in `User` to store the full name, concatenating `first_name`, `" "`, and `last_name`, because now a column named `full_name` doesn't exist in database, and I don't want to touch table structure, which requires modification to production database.

If I declare `full_name` field in the default constructor of `User` class, when I retrieve some `User` entity from database, will this field holds `first_name + " " + last_name` as I expect, or will it be `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I declare full_name field in the default constructor of User class, when I retrieve some User entity from database, will this field holds first_name + " " + last_name as I expect, or will it be null?

It will hold the string `"null null"`, because of a default constructor is invoked before a fields population.

An entity is a simple Java class. So a default constructor always is invoked in the first place, if you do `new Persist()` or `Class<Persist>.newInstance()`. The second way is how Hibernate creates objects of persistent classes.

And this approach will not solve your task, because of

```
CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?
```

is not the same

```
first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ?
```

> I don't want to generate some customized Criteria aside

I would advise you to do it. I have written such a restriction some time before

[How can I concatenate two properties into one property using hibernate criteria query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479863/3405171)

You can try to use a `@Formula` too, as described by a link above.

Comment: About the first point, thank you because I don't exactly know the order of construction of an entity and its population. About the second point, my question is well defined because the user input maybe "John", "White" or "John White", with "John" as name and "White" as surname. And the third point, to my surprise, I just found the same post after asking this question... Sometimes I don't know the exact term, such as "derived property" in this case ....Thx. Will accept your answer.