# How to get 2 fields concatenated in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Say, I've a table called "Contact" with "first_name" and "last_name" as columns in it. Basically, "select concat(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) as fullname from Contact c" is what I want to do in hibernate.

I can put the entire query inside createQuery and get desired output. But, I don't want to execute sql queries in hibernate. I found a similar post here "[Can we concatenate two properties in Hibernate HQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910428/can-we-concatenate-two-properties-in-hibernate-hql-query)". But this executes sql query and of course it has concat in where clause(I want in select clause).

Somebody please suggest an answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can introduce an artificial field in your entity and mark it with @Formula annotation

e.g.

```
@Formula("concat(first_name,' ',first_name)")
private String fullname;
```

See an example [here](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and)